# Does Google Scholar have an API available that we can use in our research applications?

Tags: journal, researchkit, google-scholar

I am working on a research publication and collaboration project that has a literature search feature in it.
Google Scholar seems like it will work since it is an open source tool, but when I researched Google Scholar, I could not find any information about it having an API.

Is there an API for Google Scholar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick search shows that others are trying to implement such APIs, but Google does not provide one. It is not clear whether this is legal, see for instance
[How to get permission from Google to use Google Scholar Data, if needed?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34970/how-to-get-permission-from-google-to-use-google-scholar-data-if-needed).

Answer (score 25):

[There's no official Google Scholar API](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34970/how-to-get-permission-from-google-to-use-google-scholar-data-if-needed/34973#34973).

There are third-party solutions like free [`scholarly`](https://github.com/scholarly-python-package/scholarly) Python package which supports [profile](https://scholarly.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#search-by-keyword-and-return-a-generator-of-author-objects), [author](https://scholarly.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#search-for-an-author-by-name-and-return-a-generator-of-author-objects), [cite](https://scholarly.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#citedby) and [organic](https://github.com/scholarly-python-package/scholarly/blob/9269ff36ad2314e6cc0c5b499efc3b79b844707e/scholarly/_scholarly.py#L24) results ([`search_pubs`](https://scholarly.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html?highlight=organic#search-pubs) seems to be the method to get organic results, although method name confuses me).

Note that by using `scholarly` constantly without a requests rate limit, Google may block your IP ([mentioned by @RadioControlled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938110/does-google-scholar-have-an-api-available-that-we-can-use-in-our-research-applic/71236400?noredirect=1#comment131414631_71236400)). Use it wisely.

Additionally, there's a [`scrape-google-scholar-py`](https://github.com/dimitryzub/scrape-google-scholar-py) module that lets you extract pretty much any Google Scholar page.

Alternatively, there's a [Google Scholar API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-api) from SerpApi which is a paid API with a free plan that supports [organic](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-organic-results), [cite](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-cite-api), [profile](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-profiles-api), [author](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-api) results and bypasses all the blocks on SerpApi backend so it won't block your IP, and it handle legal part of scraping.

---

Example code to parse profile results using `scholarly` using [`search_by_keyword`](https://scholarly.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#search-by-keyword-and-return-a-generator-of-author-objects) method:

```py
import json
from scholarly import scholarly

# will paginate to the next page by default
authors = scholarly.search_keyword("biology")

for author in authors:
    print(json.dumps(author, indent=2))

# part of the output:

'''
{
  "container_type": "Author",
  "filled": [],
  "source": "SEARCH_AUTHOR_SNIPPETS",
  "scholar_id": "LXVfPc8AAAAJ",
  "url_picture": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=medium_photo&user=LXVfPc8AAAAJ",
  "name": "Eric Lander",
  "affiliation": "Broad Institute",
  "email_domain": "",
  "interests": [
    "Biology",
    "Genomics",
    "Genetics",
    "Bioinformatics",
    "Mathematics"
  ],
  "citedby": 552013
}
... other author results
'''
```

Example using [`scrape-google-scholar-py`](https://github.com/dimitryzub/scrape-google-scholar-py#example-usage-custom-backend):

```py
from google_scholar_py import CustomGoogleScholarProfiles
import json

parser = CustomGoogleScholarProfiles()
data = parser.scrape_google_scholar_profiles(
    query='blizzard',
    pagination=False,
    save_to_csv=False,
    save_to_json=False
)
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Outputs:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Adam Lobel",
    "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=_xwYD2sAAAAJ",
    "affiliations": "Blizzard Entertainment",
    "interests": [
      "Gaming",
      "Emotion regulation"
    ],
    "email": "Verified email at AdamLobel.com",
    "cited_by_count": 3593
  }, # other results...
]
```

---

Example code to parse organic results using [Google Scholar Profile Results API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-profiles-api) from SerpApi:

```py
import json
from serpapi import GoogleScholarSearch

# search parameters
params = {
    "api_key": "Your SerpApi API key",
    "engine": "google_scholar_profiles",
    "hl": "en",                            # language
    "mauthors": "biology"                  # search query
}

search = GoogleScholarSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# only first page results
for result in results["profiles"]:
    print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))

# part of the output:
'''
{
  "name": "Masatoshi Nei",
  "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ",
  "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?author_id=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&engine=google_scholar_author&hl=en",
  "author_id": "VxOmZDgAAAAJ",
  "affiliations": "Laura Carnell Professor of Biology, Temple University",
  "email": "Verified email at temple.edu",
  "cited_by": 384074,
  "interests": [
    {
      "title": "Evolution",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aevolution",
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:evolution"
    },
    {
      "title": "Evolutionary biology",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aevolutionary_biology",
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:evolutionary_biology"
    },
    {
      "title": "Molecular evolution",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Amolecular_evolution",
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:molecular_evolution"
    },
    {
      "title": "Population genetics",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Apopulation_genetics",
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:population_genetics"
    },
    {
      "title": "Phylogenetics",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aphylogenetics",
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:phylogenetics"
    }
  ],
  "thumbnail": "https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/citations?view_op=small_photo&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citpid=3"
}
... other results
'''
```

There is a dedicated [Scrape historic Google Scholar results using Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-historic-google-scholar-results-using-python/) blog post of mine at SerpApi which shows how to scrape historic 2017-2021 Organic, Cite Google Scholar results to CSV, SQLite.

There's also a blog post about [scraping Google Scholar in R](https://dimitryzub.medium.com/scrape-google-scholar-in-r-d521cfe0e8d), if you are not a Python guy.

> Disclaimer, I work for SeprApi

Comment: Note that if you use scholarly too much you might easily have your whole organization blocked from Google Search for a while (or everyone has to enter captchas for their searches). Not recommended.

Comment: @RadioControlled thank you for explicitly mentioning it as I forgot to add it when writing this answer. I've updated the answer and added a link to your comment. Thank you 