How to bypass a timeout when webscraping
I'm relatively new to scraping and I'm currently using the scholar package in R to try to scrape information about researchers off of Google Scholar. However, I have about 500 names to scrape, so I get timed out from Google.
To get around this, I've tried setting a timer that pauses after each additional name is scraped, but I still get timed out.
for (i in seq_len(nrow(info))) {
  # Get the Google Scholar ID 
  id <- get_scholar_id(last_name = info$last_name[i],
                        first_name = info$first_name[i],
                        affiliation = "School Name")
  # Store the ID 
  scholar_ids[i] <- id
  
  sleep_time <- runif(n = 1, min = 2, max = 4)
  Sys.sleep(sleep_time)
}

where "info" is a data frame where the first and last names are stored. The data frame will be updated as information is scarped.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about this?

What did you try? Please show the R code related to "I've tried setting a timer".

These may be generally helpful links, though they don't go to your specific question: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938110/does-google-scholar-have-an-api-available-that-we-can-use-in-our-research-applic and (2) https://dimitryzub.medium.com/scrape-google-scholar-in-r-d521cfe0e8d

What error are you getting exactly? Google Scholar will send HTTP response 429 (at some point in the past after no more than 20 requests per day), but scholar seems to implement client-side rate limiting as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I suspect that the approach you are using with the randomised delays might have resulted in a series of requests with a short delay, that in turn would have triggered a rate limit from Google Scholar. My experience with this is that the rate limit will be associated with your IP for some time. Not sure when it might expire. You could try waiting or, if possible, running the crawler through a VPN or proxy that will effectively give you a different IP address.
I'd then suggest using a deterministic delay. My testing indicates that 15 seconds is a delay which will not get you throttled by Google Scholar.
Here's a test script that replicates a data frame with name and affiliation values. The resulting data frame has 500 entries. It then goes and iterates over those entries. Rather than using a for loop I'd suggest using purrr::pmap_chr(), but you can adapt this to a simple for loop too.
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(scholar)

# Create some test data.
info <- tribble(
  ~first_name, ~last_name, ~affiliation,
  "Maggie", "Collier", NA,
  "Dennis", "Lichtenberger", NA,
  "Ingo", "Steinbach", "Ruhr-Universitaet Bochum",
  "Michael", "Sander", "ETH Zurich",
  "ray", "craib", NA
)
# Replicate the test data to 500 records.
info <- bind_rows(replicate(100, info, simplify = FALSE))

nrow(info)

scholar_ids <- pmap_chr(info, function(...) {
  print(Sys.time())
  Sys.sleep(15)
  get_scholar_id(...)
})

With the 15 second delay it will take a while (around 2 hours) to crawl all of the entries. Always better to crawl slowly and not get yourself blocked or throttled.
